# Kubuntu 14.04. Could not write file. Disk full

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu

Just did a fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Now I'm trying to place a file in the firmware folder.
"Could not write file. Disk full." keeps popping up
even though the HD is obviously not full.
Done this operation many times before (Mint KDE and Leeenux).
Anyone?

Comment: what is the output of `df` , `df -i`, and `lsblk`? What type of file system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about copying something to `/lib/firmware/` there are a few things you need to check:

- You're doing it as the right user. It's `drwxr-xr-x 74 root root` so only root can write in there. That means you'll want to run something like:

  ```
  sudo cp /path/to/firmware.file /lib/firmware/
  ```

  This would be the most common issue but I get a "Access denied" error instead of disk full.
- Is `/lib/firmware/` on a weird partition that ***is*** full? Here's mine:

  ```
  $ df /lib/firmware/
  Filesystem                    1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
  /dev/sda1 115256744 97007904  12371040  89% /
  ```
- Are you in readonly mode? Check the mount options:

  ```
  $ mount | grep "on $(df /lib/firmware | awk 'NR==2 {print $6}') "
  /dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,discard,errors=remount-ro)
  ```

Comment: Thanx. Got it figured, wrong firmware folder.